# How to fix error running ./gradlew check connectedCheck, after update AndroidStudio to 0.4.0?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After the update of the AndroidStudio, I updated the gradle to `1.9` in the wrapper and to `0.7.+` in the dependencies of the build.gradle.

Since then, I get this error when running ./gradlew check connectedCheck

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Lint found errors with abortOnError=true; aborting build.
```

**EDIT**

The gradle console also shows these messages:

```
Ran lint on variant release: 69 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 69 issues found
Wrote XML report to <PROJECT>/app/build/lint-results.xml
Wrote HTML report to <PROJECT>/app/build/lint-results.html
:app:lint FAILED
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should see what the lint errors are and fix them (some of these can be quite important so you should give them a look); the **Gradle Console** should have a more detailed error message if you don't find anything in the error pane. If you'd like to have it not abort your build when there's a lint error, then the error message gives you a clue what you should do: add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Read more: [gradle build fails on lint task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699147/gradle-build-fails-on-lint-task)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've seem this option, but I didn't want to do this modification for now. Before do that I'd like to know why now there are these errors that abort the build, because I didn't change anything in the code. Only the gradle versions

Comment: No. Any error is displayed by the console. It shows that there are some issues, and indicates two files, wich contains some issues. My question is edited. Please look there.

Comment: Is it possible to do this from a top level script such as the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420391/how-to-disable-lint-abortonerror-in-android-gradle-plugin-from-top-level-of-mult?