# RedPhone Build Failed

Tags: gradle, lint

I tried to build Redphone for my android device using gradle.
I always get the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lint'.
> Lint found errors with abortOnError=true; aborting build.
```

What exactly is the error and how to correct.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build can be completed by adding the following to build.gradle

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Tried the solution by Scott Barta and Jared Burrows at [How to fix error running ./gradlew check connectedCheck, after update AndroidStudio to 0.4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981897/how-to-fix-error-running-gradlew-check-connectedcheck-after-update-androidstu) and it worked.