# Unable to build slidingmenu with gradle, failing on lint

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, lint

I am getting the following error when I try to build sliding menu project. This project was used in eclipse but I used default import in android studio to get this project.

> :slidingMenu:lint FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':slidingMenu:lint'.
>
>   > [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 9.59 secs Could not execute build using Gradle
>   distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.

Running with --stacktrace didn't give any new info.

I've tried adding an ignore as mentioned in this answer - [gradle build fails on lint task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699147/gradle-build-fails-on-lint-task) but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Did the import create a build.gradle in slidingmenu? That might be the problem if it is not defined as a library:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

I don't have it set up as a library in this way though. I include it in the app's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile project(':slidingmenu:library')
}
```

and in settings.gradle:

```
include ':slidingmenu:library'
```