# Android build error when updating to a newer version of Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, build, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to build a large Android project that I was previously running on Android Studio 0.5.2 on 0.8.1.  While it builds without errors on 0.5.2, on 0.8.1 the Gradle build fails with some unusual errors, including the following:

```
 Error:(161) Error: The id "buttonMarkUnread" is not defined anywhere. [UnknownId]
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonMarkUnread"
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Explanation for issues of type "UnknownId": 
The @+id/ syntax refers to an existing id, or creates a new one if it has
not already been defined elsewhere. However, this means that if you have a
typo in your reference, or if the referred view no longer exists, you do
not get a warning since the id will be created on demand. This check
catches errors where you have renamed an id without updating all of the
references to it.

Error: Suspicious method call; should probably call "layout" rather than "onLayout" [WrongCall]
```

The weird thing is the error messages seem sort of "linty"; that is they seem more like "gotchas" than actual compile errors (that is, they should be warnings).  Is there a reason that these are compile errors in the newer versions of AS, and is there a simple fix when it comes to correcting `UnknownId`, `WrongCall`, `DuplicateIds`, and `notSibling` errors?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699147/gradle-build-fails-on-lint-task