# Display classes containing deprecation Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deprecated

I updated my project to the latest Android APIs and the project now has multiple deprecated methods. Does Android Studio have a cool way of listing all classes containing said methods, such as the TODO window? I know I can go through every class and search methodically through the code, but I would rather like to make it easy on myself.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

If it helps someone else heres the answer to my question:

If you go to *Analyze* -> *Inspect Code...*

When your project has been inspected click on *Code maturity issues* and tada, there is a list of all Deprecated API usages :)

**UPDATE: May 2021**

Deprecation warnings are now found under your respective language.

**Kotlin** -> *Migration* -> *Usage of redundant or deprecated syntax or deprecated symbols*

[image: Kotlin deprecation]

**Java** -> *Code maturity*

[image: Java deprecation]

Comment: It doesn't show deprecated methods ("Code maturity issues" is not listed).

Comment: @CoolMind in your IDE you can go to **File -> Editor -> Inspection**
Please make sure that you have ticked **Code maturity under Java** and **Migration under Kotlin**.

Answer (score 75):

Follow below steps:
**Go to Analyze -> Run Inspectinon By Name ->type Deprecated API Usage**

In the latest Android Studio 2021.3.1+
**Go to Code -> Analyze Code -> Run Inspectinon By Name ->type Deprecated API Usage**

Comment: Please make sure your minSdkVersion value is proper. This tool will show all the deprecated APIs in source code below the minSdkVersion value.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [How to recompile with -Xlint:deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711773/how-to-recompile-with-xlintdeprecation), add into *root* `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    ...
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

or in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
allprojects {
    ...
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
            options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")
        }
    }
}
```

Then start in Terminal:

```
./gradlew lint
```

or in `Gradle` menu:

[image]

It will show warnings, but also can fail after 3 errors:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Lint found errors in the project;
> aborting build.
>
> Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build
> script to proceed with errors:
>
> ```
> android {
>     lintOptions {
>         abortOnError false
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The first 3 errors (out of 4) were:

Adding these lines in `app/build.gradle` won't help. You should fix all errors and try to launch `Lint` again.

If you have many errors, you can show [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699147/gradle-build-fails-on-lint-task) of [them](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/LintOptions):

```
android { 
    lintOptions { 
        // abortOnError false 
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        isAbortOnError = false
        // if true, show all locations for an error, do not truncate lists, etc.
        isShowAll = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this works, the accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your app folder (module) with "Android" selected in the Project explorer and then go to **Analyze** -> **Inspect Code...**

It will run for a few minutes and then show you deprecated classes as well as other things you might want to fix.