# How to recompile with -Xlint:deprecation

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I don't use Android Studio but I build everything from the command line using `build.gradle`. I generate a Lint report like this:

```
./gradlew lint
```

This correctly generates a Lint report but it also says this:

```
Note: MyActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

This makes me wonder how I can do that? I've tried the following:

```
./gradlew lint -Xlint:deprecation
```

But it doesn't work. It says:

```
Problem configuring task :app:lint from command line.
Unknown command-line option '-X'.
```

So how can I pass `-Xlint:deprecation` to Lint via gradle?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

To answer my own question, you need to add the following to your project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    ...

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: which `build.gradle`?

Comment: The one in the `app` directory.

Comment: @Andreas, this did nothing for me and I placed it in `app/android/build.gradle` and then I tried `app/build.gradle`

Comment: This has to go into the project-level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Kotlin equivalent is `tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")}`

Comment: A command is `gradlew lint`, not `gradlew lint -Xlint:deprecation`! I wasted too much time.

Comment: Worked like a charm but don't know why. Can you explain a bit?

Answer (score 3):

Just an update from me since I ran into this issue recently:

You can get the details for this deprecation issue by doing as @Andreas suggested in the accepted answer. If you're using Kotlin, the real solution is (in build.gradle):

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")
        }
    }
}
```

One other solution is to update your AndroidSDK. The issue is with an SDK method overriding a deprecated feature. In your build.gradle file you can change the compileSdkVersion:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29 //Change this to the latest release
    ...
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 29 //Change this too
        ...
    }
}
```

Using the latest SDK version will likely fix your issue. Android does a good job of fixing deprecation issue between releases. If it persists, you might just need to wait until the next SDK release. If the issue isn't in the AndroidSDK but instead in a package you've downloaded, you should see if the package needs upgrading or contact the manager of that package.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin (build.gradle.kts) version of the other answers:

```
allprojects {    
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {

        tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
            options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf("-parameters", "-Xlint:deprecation"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added in-app level build.gradle and resolved issue

```
aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290618/2987755) is an accepted answer but solved this with Gradle [`Java` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) as below.
Add java plugin to `build.gradle` file if not added already.

```java
plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id "java"
}
```

Then add task [`compileJava`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) and/or `compileTestJava` based on your need to check deprecations for only java main source code or java test source code.
You can add various compile options as listed [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions)

```java
compileTestJava {
   // options.incremental = true
   // options.fork = true
   // options.failOnError = false
    options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")
}
```

Also, we can specify for the main and test sourcecode project as

```java
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to build.gradle solved my problem

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
```