# Flutter: FlutterFirebaseInstanceIDService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Integrating Firebase messaging service in flutter app and using latest `firebase_messaging:^3.0.0` gradle in the flutter but while installing app showing error and I have already reinstall the app many times.

```
FlutterFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
FlutterFirebaseInstanceIDService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

I have added these line in `build.gradle` in the android section, still showing the same error. I have taken ref. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711773/how-to-recompile-with-xlintdeprecation).

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
```

How to resolve this error `-Xlint:deprecation` for flutter.

Comment: See [FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129304/7666442)

Comment: @NileshRathod how can i manage with flutter?

Comment: You can check here [Firebase Cloud Messaging for Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging#-readme-tab-)

Comment: @NileshRathod I have already followed this tutorial.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try few things:

Paste these lines at the end of `gradle.properties` file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Changes in file `app\build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

...

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}
```

Optionally you can add code inside `subproject{}` in file `android\build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    ...
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
        }
    }
}
```

Go to terminal and launch command

```
flutter clean
```

Build the App Again.

Answer (score 0):

in your android/app/build.gradle file set the minSdkVersion 21

or

add this implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0" in your dependencies at android/app/build.gradle file