# Error when include image_picker inside project (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

Why is this error keep coming when i'm executing my project? It occur once i put the image_picker in my pubspec.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Android resource linking failed
>     Output:  /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:331: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>     /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:331: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>     error: failed linking references.
>     Command: /Users/s/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/6d65e55edb223325e7c5119d99552582/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
>             /Users/s/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
>             --manifest\
>             /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
>             -o\
>             /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
>             -R\
>             @/Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>             --auto-add-overlay\
>             --java\
>             /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
>             --custom-package\
>             com.example.a\
>             -0\
>             apk\
>             --output-text-symbols\
>             /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
>             --no-version-vectors
>     Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
>     Output:  /Users/s/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-27.1.1.aar/fa938137e4d19d1dd06a6895b6e14886/res/values/values.xml:96:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> /Users/s/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-27.1.1.aar/fa938137e4d19d1dd06a6895b6e14886/res/values/values.xml:96:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>     error: failed linking references.
>     Command: /Users/s/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/6d65e55edb223325e7c5119d99552582/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
>             /Users/s/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
>             --manifest\
>             /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
>             -o\
>             /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
>             -R\
>             @/Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>             --auto-add-overlay\
>             --java\
>             /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
>             --custom-package\
>             com.example.a\
>             -0\
>             apk\
>             --output-text-symbols\
>             /Users/s/Desktop/Flutter/a/build/app/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
>             --no-version-vectors
>     Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0

Comment: To fix it try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460559/10269042

Comment: What is your compileSdkVersion (under android/app/build.gradle)?

Comment: @PhucTran 27 and for min i put 21

Comment: @ali Can you try my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your compileSdkVersion to 28 (under android/app/build.gradle)

> compileSdkVersion 28

Then run the command

> flutter clean

Then run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

@PhucTran answer's is correct.
Just want to add that i had to `Invalidate Cache` from Android Studio and Restart it.

```
File-> Invalidate Cahe and Restart
```