# Flutter run on new location package throws error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

I have created a basic android flutter application using Android Studio. I remember running this app few times but all of a sudden it doesnt run. Tried changing the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28 as per few helps out there, but this did not work. Trying to understand the base of the problem since I am very new to Android development.

What I noticed:
Below error is thrown only when I add geolocator or location package in pubspec.yaml and import it. If I remove it, the app works fine

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.
dir\values\values.xml:197: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\value
s\values.xml:198: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\digi_yb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\0a870866429dd545bdd071cb7f1
72c92\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManif
est\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResource
s\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resou
rces-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\process
DebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          de.digi3.digi3app\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\digi_yb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0-rc01.aar\037167aeb6c73f9e63ab1315d785696d\res\va
lues\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\digi_yb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0-rc01.aar\037167aeb6c73f9e63ab1315d785696d\res\values\valu
es.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\digi_yb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\0a870866429dd545bdd071cb7f1
72c92\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManif
est\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResource
s\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resou
rces-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\process
DebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          de.digi3.digi3app\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\digi_yb\Documents\flutter_tests\digi3_app\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --sca
n to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         15.3s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472636/error-when-include-image-picker-inside-project-flutter

Answer (score 1):

The error tells me you have not updated your compile SDK version. :) "android-27" means you're still using compile SDK version 27. Perhaps you forgot to save or something else is overriding it? It should be version 28.

Comment: I am not sure, because this error arise only when I add geolocator or location package in pubspec.yaml and import it. If I remove it, app works fine