# Flutter cloud_firestore(0.9.0) package crashes when opening the app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

Flutter firebase firestore package crashes when opening the app, here is the log file,

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101): Failed to handlemethod call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101): 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Firestore component is not present.
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at 
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:787)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:86)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:78)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getFirestore(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:82)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getCollectionReference(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:87)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getQuery(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:139)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.onMethodCall(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:463)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:200)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView$PlatformMessageHandlerImpl.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterNativeView.java:188)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:202)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) 
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method 
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(28101):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Here are some more logs,

```
E/flutter (28101): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(186)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (28101): PlatformException(error, Firestore component is not present., null)
E/flutter (28101): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter (28101): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:292:18)
E/flutter (28101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28101): #2      Query.snapshots.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/chathura/Flutter/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3/lib/src/query.dart:56:37)
E/flutter (28101): #3      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:805:24)
E/flutter (28101): #4      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
E/flutter (28101): #5      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:818:19)
E/flutter (28101): #6      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
E/flutter (28101): #7      _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:135:37)
E/flutter (28101): #8      _StreamBuilderBaseState.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:109:5)
E/flutter (28101): #9      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3830:58)
E/flutter (28101): #10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (28101): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (28101): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (28101): #13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (28101): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (28101): #15     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
E/flutter (28101): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (28101): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (28101): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (28101): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (28101): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (28101): #21     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
E/flutter (28101): #22     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (28101): #23     ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4047:11)
E/flutter (28101): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (28101): #25     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4965:32)
E/flutter (28101): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (28101): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (28101): #28     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (28101): #29     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (28101): #30     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
E/flutter (28101): #31     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
E/flutter (28101): #32     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (28101): #33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (28101): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (28101): #35     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (28101): #36     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (28101): #37     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
E/flutter (28101): #38     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (28101): #39     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (28101): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (28101): #41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (28101): #42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (28101): #43     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
E/flutter (28101): #44     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/wi
```

This is my app level gradle file,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
}
```

This is the module level gradle file,

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
}
```

The version of firestore package,

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0
```

Is it a gardle issue or plugin issue?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460559/10269042

Comment: @anmol.majhail I tried this, this doesn't work

Comment: What is your Complie SDK version .?

Comment: @anmol.majhail 28

Comment: minSdkVersion 21
      &  targetSdkVersion 28 ?? You Still get same error after making the changes. ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27

Comment: Change it to - minSdkVersion 21 & targetSdkVersion 28 & then try.

Comment: make sure you run flutter clean first before building

Comment: @anmol.majhail Yes, it is working now, can you add this as an answer please? also I would like to know the reason for this issue. you can mention them in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Things:

Paste these lines at the end of `gradle.properties` file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Changes in file `app\build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

...

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}
```

Go to terminal and launch command

```
flutter clean
```

then Build again.

As Mentioned in  [CHANGELOG](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-changelog-tab-) of `cloud_firestore 0.9.0`:

> 0.9.0 # Breaking change. Migrate from the deprecated original Android Support Library to AndroidX. This shouldn't result in any functional
>   changes, but it requires any Android apps using this plugin to also
>   migrate if they're using the original support library.

Comment: what made you to say that changing min sdk to 21 and target to 28?

Comment: I read it somewhere on Flutter github issues.. plus its Latest Version - flutter further updates will add it too. stable channel has not being updated yet.