# Please help me CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.( unchecked or unsafe operations.)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I've tried everything i see on the net to solve this problem for a day.Downgrade versions add something in gradle or rebuild etc. in short i am tring to use firebase.

For every solution i try, the error changes, but it doesn't end. Here is my mysterious gradles and pubspec. in android/app/gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

  android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {

        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
   }
 }
   dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
 }
```

in android/gradle

```
   ...
  buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
 }
}
  allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
 }
 ...
```

in pubspech.yaml:

```
   path_provider: ^1.2.0
   sembast: ^2.0.1+2
   flutter_bloc: ^0.21.0
   equatable: ^0.5.1

   cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+3
```

I would be grateful if someone help i also tried app plugin google service or change google services to 3.2.1 or minsdkversions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer for my case tried all of them, but it fixed when targetsdk and min sdk used same time
[Flutter: FlutterFirebaseInstanceIDService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458747/flutter-flutterfirebaseinstanceidservice-java-uses-or-overrides-a-deprecated-ap?rq=1)