# Android Studio 3.6.2 Java Compilier switches

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio 3.6.2
I get the following message when I build my application:

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   Note: D:\AndroidProjects\NightLight\app\src\main\java\com\example\nightlight\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

I can't find any information on how to change the Java compiler command line.
Any information would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290618/8837882:

```
allprojects {
    ...

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }   
}
```