# How to find all deprecated methods / classes in a Flutter project (Android studio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Everything is in the title, i have tried the basic analyzer from Android Studio but it has not inspection for `dart` files...

How can i do the equivalent of `Analyze -> Run Inspectinon By Name ->type Deprecated API Usage` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37894469/11665178) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command to see the list of all the warnings related to your project.

```dart
dart analyze
```

Comment: thanks i used `dart analyze | grep deprecated` and it gave me the output i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dart fix

To see a full list of available changes, run the following command:

```
dart fix --dry-run
```

To apply all changes in bulk, run the following command:

```
dart fix --apply
```

For more info
https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix

Comment: thanks for the command it also works very similar to `dart analyze` actually.