# Custom linting rules failing with com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, lint

My team and I develop Android apps and have decided on coding guidelines that all should follow. I therefore started implementing custom lint rules which can be found [here](https://github.com/apertomove/linette), and have added it to our automated build process in Jenkins.

The problem we are now having is that these rules no longer work after upgrading our Android projects from
`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'` to
`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'`

We continually get the error:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.JavaContext.getContents()Ljava/lang/String;`

When switching back to `gradle 2.2.0` all is fine, the custom rules are checked and the app builds.

I tried updating gradle in the lint repository and unfortunately have the exact same issue in my [TodoDetector](https://github.com/apertomove/linette/blob/apertomove-linette/lint/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/linette/detectors/TodoDetector.java) at line 72. In Android studio all dependencies are resolved fine, but when trying  to build and deploy the library with `./gradlew clean build test install`, We get the error listed above.

I've been searching all day and have yet to find a viable solution for this problem. Any help, tips or advice is greatly appreciated.

**Terminal output**

```
:clean
:aarWrapper:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build
:aarWrapper:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:checkDebugManifest
:aarWrapper:prepareDebugDependencies
:aarWrapper:compileDebugAidl
:aarWrapper:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:compileLint
:aarWrapper:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:mergeDebugShaders
:aarWrapper:compileDebugShaders
:aarWrapper:generateDebugAssets
:aarWrapper:mergeDebugAssets
:aarWrapper:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:compileDebugRenderscript
:aarWrapper:generateDebugResValues
:aarWrapper:generateDebugResources
:aarWrapper:packageDebugResources
:aarWrapper:processDebugManifest
:aarWrapper:generateDebugBuildConfig
:aarWrapper:processDebugResources
:aarWrapper:generateDebugSources
:aarWrapper:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:aarWrapper:javaPreCompileDebug
:aarWrapper:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:aarWrapper:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:aarWrapper:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:aarWrapper:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:aarWrapper:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:aarWrapper:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
:aarWrapper:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:aarWrapper:bundleDebug
:aarWrapper:compileDebugSources
:aarWrapper:assembleDebug
:aarWrapper:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:checkReleaseManifest
:aarWrapper:prepareReleaseDependencies
:aarWrapper:compileReleaseAidl
:aarWrapper:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:mergeReleaseShaders
:aarWrapper:compileReleaseShaders
:aarWrapper:generateReleaseAssets
:aarWrapper:mergeReleaseAssets
:aarWrapper:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:compileReleaseRenderscript
:aarWrapper:generateReleaseResValues
:aarWrapper:generateReleaseResources
:aarWrapper:packageReleaseResources
:aarWrapper:processReleaseManifest
:aarWrapper:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:aarWrapper:processReleaseResources
:aarWrapper:generateReleaseSources
:aarWrapper:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:aarWrapper:javaPreCompileRelease
:aarWrapper:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:aarWrapper:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:aarWrapper:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:aarWrapper:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:aarWrapper:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:aarWrapper:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:aarWrapper:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
:aarWrapper:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:aarWrapper:bundleRelease
:aarWrapper:compileReleaseSources
:aarWrapper:assembleRelease
:aarWrapper:assemble
:aarWrapper:lint FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':aarWrapper:lint'.
> com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.JavaContext.getContents()Ljava/lang/String;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

**gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

allprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:24.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.0.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.3.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.tools.lint:lint-tests:24.3.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.tools:testutils:24.3.1'
}

jar {
    baseName 'com.bignerdranch.linette'
    version '1.0'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Manifest-Version': 1.0
        attributes('Lint-Registry': 'com.bignerdranch.linette.registry.CustomIssueRegistry')
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["lint/src/main/java"]
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["lint/src/test/java"]
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    lintChecks
}

dependencies {
    lintChecks files(jar)
}

defaultTasks 'assemble'

task install(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.lintChecks
    into System.getProperty('user.home') + '/.android/lint/'
}
```

**aarWrapper gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    def compileLint = project.tasks.getByPath(':aarWrapper:compileLint')
    compileLint.dependsOn parent.tasks.getByName("jar")
    compileLint << {
        copy {
            from '../build/libs'
            into 'build/intermediates/lint'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried rebuild your project and run after disabling instant run?

Comment: @pRaNaY I currently am not a big fan of instant run and have it deactivated. Unfortunately the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

If your deactivation of instant run not works then add it on your `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Then clean your project and run.

if `abortOnError false` not resolve your issue, then you can try the following

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

**Resource Link:**

1. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/e6a5b9c7c1bca4da402de442315b5ff1ada819c7
2. [gradle build fails on lint task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699147/gradle-build-fails-on-lint-task)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying out the same code and bumped into the same issue.

There are new versions available for `com.android.tools.lint`. Try 25.2.0 or above, and you will notice that the example code TodoDetector uses deprecated methods.

Basically, you need to make your class implement `Detector.JavaPsiScanner` instead of `Detector.JavaScanner`.

http://static.javadoc.io/com.android.tools.lint/lint-api/25.3.0/com/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Detector.JavaPsiScanner.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated to `'com.android.tools.lint:lint:25.2.0'` and replaced the `Detector.JavaScanner` with `Detector.JavaPsiScanner`. Unfortunately, I still have the same error message. The only difference however is that it now references the new method `createPsiVisitor`

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Passos has given a solution here in [this tutorial](http://blog.passos.me/android_lint_ignore_specific_errors/)

### Ignoring Erros

Lint is part of Gradle build process, by default if it fail your build will stop and you will get a message like it:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
```

In 99% of the cases people will start ignore lint instead of fix the problems, adding this on `build.gradle` app

```
lintOptions {   
    abortOnError false   
}
```

But IMHO it’s wrong. If lint is telling, you have a problem the best thing to do is fix it. Lint is a tools to make your app and the UX better.

### Ignoring specific erros

Sometimes you really need to ignore some lint errors. For example, when you are using `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` in your WebView

In this case, you should disable only the specific ids instead of disabling the whole lint.

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'SetJavaScriptEnabled'
}
```

You also can ignore it directly in your code:

```
@SuppressLint "SetJavaScriptEnabled")
```

Or in your XML

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="SomeLintIssueIdHere" >
```

If you prefer you can move all your issues rules from a `lint.xml` file in the root directory of your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="SetJavaScriptEnabled" severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, however neither of your answers solves my problem. In our custom linting project, I can no longer build the tests after changing 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0' to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'. Changing the linting options is not a viable solution. Your more than welcome to look into the code repository found [here](https://github.com/apertomove/linette)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when migrating to Android Gradle plugin 2.3.0 `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0`. The problem in my case was that the android-apt plugin that I used has become deprecated: Android Gradle plugin 2.3.0 has annotation processing out of the box and seems to block android-apt.

Read the migration guide and migrate the "apt" section of your gradle build script and "apt" dependencies, then remove the android-apt plugin:
https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration

**UPD:** The problem was still there after the fix above. I looked into the error stacktrace in Event Log and found out that the exception happens in one of my custom lint checkers (`io.vokal.lint:todo:1.0.3`). Removing it from `~/.android/lint` solved the problem.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, we don't have android-apt in our gradle script... I also removed the rules from `~/.android/lint` but still have the problem described above.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Looking into `context.getContents()`:

`return mDriver.getClient().readFile(file);`

So i tried to do it manually like this: `context.getDriver().getClient().readFile(context.file)` which throws the same error message.

My workaround now is, instead of using `context.getContents()` i just use `context.file` and read it out without the driver. I am not sure if this is a good way but for me it works.

So here the working code:

```
static void someMethod(com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Context context){
    readFile(context.file)
    ...
}

static String readFile(File file) {
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    Charset encoding = Charset.defaultCharset();
    try {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);

    } catch (IOException e){
        return "";
    }
}
```