# Skip lint in Android build in Vsts

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, azure-pipelines, lint

I put an Android project in Git in VSTS and created a build. The build always stops at "gradlew build" step and in the log I see "Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.".

I can find the problem when running Analyze in Android studio, but I haven't been able to solve the problem (related to All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification...Examples include 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0' and 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0')

I want to run the build now to see that the build process is working. How can I (temporarily) skip lint? I haven't found any settings, not in the project files nor in Vsts build settings., to control this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app's build.gradle I added

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

Solution found here [gradle build fails on lint task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699147/gradle-build-fails-on-lint-task)