# Build.gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

Can you please help me my problem for android studio?
Thank you very much!

This is my problem:

[image]

Comment: did you try clean and rebuild project?

Comment: try the latest version firebase 11.6.2

Comment: error is itself written in message

Comment: your support libraries version should be same and one more read logcate you can see a solution in last by modifying gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update **Project** gradle

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Update You **APP** Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

You need Firebase Version `10.2.0` or above to For Working in Oreo. So Update both Messaging and Core Gradle of Firebase

[How to Use Firebase in your Android Application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: @KovácsArnold Update the Project Gradle. I had Updated that in the Edit

Comment: yes, I update @Tomin B

http://prntscr.com/hmes57
and: http://prntscr.com/hmesj9

but something bad :(

Comment: @KovácsArnold : Change All Firebase GradleFiles to Same Version. that is Firebase Ads , and Core. You also added 2 Firebase Core Gradle. Fix it mahn.

Comment: You Compiled ormlite library twice. remove all duplicate Compilation

Comment: thank you mate! all okay, and now new problem:
http://prntscr.com/hmewjf

brrr :/

Comment: @KovácsArnold : You had added 2 Firebase-Core gradle mahn. Remove it.

Comment: Please Remove All Duplicate Entries.

Comment: Teo of your Application Have same Resourece file or in Smae name. That Causes the error. It can be Caused by any of the Firebase Gradles.

Comment: Add `android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}`

Comment: Can yu please help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699147/gradle-build-fails-on-lint-task this is how abortOnerror False os to be added

Answer (score 0):

add below lines in your `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your libs version for firebase 
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'`

previously you are using 10 but as you are targeting Android O you have to use the version greater than 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your firebase dependency with latest version in order to work it with android Oreo.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
}
```

and you have to add these lines to your **android** tag in gradle file.

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```