# build.gradle (project) completely different?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I setup a new (Kotlin) project using Android Studio. When I take a look at my `build.gradle (Project)`, I see this content:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[However, other `build.gradle`s seem to be completely different.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47770141/9878135)

I searched all files, but couldn't find any occurrences of the `buildscript`, `dependencies` or any other block.

Where are they or how do I add them?

Comment: Have you checked the `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: in case of `buildscripts` you have to add them manually like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71549754/9737384

Answer (score 2):

buildscript was used to add the version of dependencies and classpaths. In the newer versions of android studio you have to mention the version directly after the dependency implementations.

So for example, I wanted to add the classpath *"androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin"* to my build.gradle(Project) for the plugin id *"androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"* , but in the newer version it has been moved to settings.gradle and is done by adding a resolutionStrategy block just after the repositories block: -

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin') {
                useModule("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after that, you can add the plugin id *"androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"* in plugin block in the build.gradle(Module) and sync it: -

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

Hope this is helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two `build.gradle` files in android studio i.e. `build.gradle(Project)` & `build.gradle(Module)`.
Required blocks like `buildscript`, `dependencies` are available in `build.gradle(Module)`

[image]

`build.gradle(Module)` looks like:

[image]

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Repositories have been moved to `settings.gradle` and module Gradle has been moved to the `app` package gradle.