# Cannot access includeAndroidResource It is private in UnitTestOptions

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-testing, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I was trying **Kotlin Gradle Script** and **Android Testing**.

When I try to configure android resource for Testing I get the following error :

> Cannot access includeAndroidResource It is private in UnitTestOptions.

[image]

What is the proper way to **enable** using **android Resource in Android Unit testing?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After posting this question, I went back to **Android Studio** and tried to see what's there for autocomplete.  **I pressed** `Control+Space` just after `testOptions.unitTests.` **and boom**, there was the option called `isIncludeAndroidResources` which was kotlin getter in **TestOptions** class for

```
private includeAndroidResource
```

which I then set to `true`.

**Solution** :

```
 testOptions.unitTests.isIncludeAndroidResources = true
```

**Lesson**: Try to write a question to explain the problem, sometimes answer is inside your own head.